# How to strip every extra information from an executable?

Tags: binary, header-files, elf

When creating the final binary, executable or library, too many informations are being added to it.

I would like to strip everything that is not strictly essential and vital for the binary itself; for example i would like to make useless and utility like `readelf` ( Linux ).

How i can do this in the most correct way ? I'm used to the gcc suite and/or clang.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to strip everything that is not strictly essential and vital for the binary itself

Try `objcopy --strip-unneeded`

> for example i would like to make useless and utility like readelf

Useless for what purpose? The only way to make `readelf` completely useless is to make your file be a non-ELF (but then it wouldn't run).